# httpwebrequest in windows phone 8 app throws "The remote server returned an error: NotFound."?

Tags: httpwebrequest, windows-phone-8, httpwebresponse, windows-phone-8-emulator

i am developing an windows phone 8 app , in my app i am calling services and downloading some data into my app.

i am testing my app in windows phone 8 emulator, many times it throws this error :

**"The remote server returned an error: NotFound."**

This is how i have created and used my httpwebrequest :-

```
public async Task<string> ServiceRequest(string serviceurl, string request, string methodname)
        {
            string response = "";
            try
            {

                var httpwebrequest = WebRequest.Create(new Uri(serviceurl)) as HttpWebRequest;
                httpwebrequest.Method = "POST";
                httpwebrequest.Headers["SOAPAction"] = "http://tempuri.org/" + iTestservice + "/" + methodname + "";
                httpwebrequest.ContentType = "text/xml";


                byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(request);
                using (var requestStream = await Task<Stream>.Factory.FromAsync(httpwebrequest.BeginGetRequestStream, httpwebrequest.EndGetRequestStream, null))
                {
                    await requestStream.WriteAsync(data, 0, data.Length);
                }

                var httpTask = httpRequest(httpwebrequest);
            var completeTask = await Task.WhenAny(httpTask, TaskEx.Delay(300000));
            if (completeTask == httpTask)
                return await httpTask;
            else
                httpwebrequest.Abort();
            throw new TimeoutException("Service Timed Out");

        }
        catch (TimeoutException Tex)
        {
            throw Tex;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
        public async Task<string> httpRequest(HttpWebRequest request)
        {
            string received;

            using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)(await Task<WebResponse>.Factory.FromAsync(request.BeginGetResponse, request.EndGetResponse, null)))
            {
                using (var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    using (var sr = new StreamReader(responseStream))
                    {

                        received = await sr.ReadToEndAsync();
                    }
                }
            }

            return received;
        }
```

**i am really not able to figure what was the issue**

Please note :-

i tried to open the site (service URL which my app is trying to access) in my emulator browser , it opened correctly , i wasn't facing any issues.

1)is that the problem with my code, if so i request you please correct me  ??

2)is this any emulator issue or any connectivity issue ??

3)is this any certification issue opening in emulator ??

Even after a long research to how to fix the issue i was not able to fix it .

Please Help me out.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: If you can try using the Fiddler tool (http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) to see what the network traffic is between your emulator and server. It can be a little fiddly to set up however and on some corporate networks it is blocked.

Comment: first of all thanks for the reply , even with fiddler i was not able to figure out the issue , along with in blogs they are suggesting to close fiddler when running app . since when Fiddler is attached to the networking stack it might be causing the issue. Will there be any other issue creating this problem ??
i wanted to know will this problem raise even when we have deployed app in real device also or this happens only in simulator ????
please let me know .
thanks in advance.

Comment: If you tried on a phone and it worked it may be a problem with your wired network from PC. If you never got it to work at all then certification is the least of your worries.

Answer (score 0):

I have come across this issue when the webservice requests take longer than 60 seconds. I have read reports that the emulator does not throw this error, but only an actual device. In my experience however, I have had this happen on both emulator and device. This is a default timeout setting that cannot be altered, even if you change it in the config. This issue has been around since WP7.

I've only found this question asked/blogged about once elsewhere. Seems that not a lot of people have picked this up.

AFAIK, Microsoft are aware of this, but don't plan on fixing it. (Proven by the fact that it has been around since WP7, and wasn't fixed for WP8). My guess is that they are of the opinion that web calls shouldn't be taking longer than 60 seconds in any case.

Answer (score 0):

I just resolved it adding empty credentials to https requests, like this

```
    httpwebrequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("", "");
```

here he explains why

http://blog.toetapz.com/2010/11/15/windows-phone-7-and-making-https-rest-api-calls-with-basic-authentication/